# libmysql.dll for 64bit Qt w/ MSVS2017 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I was always working with MinGW and all I had to do to not get the infamous output was to copy a 32bit libmysql.dll file to where the executable resides:

> QSqlDatabase: MYSQL driver not loaded
>
> QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Now I'm trying to compile my application with MSVS2017 64bit compiler. I've tried to use both the 32bit and 64bit `libmysql.dll` files but with no luck - I'm getting the warnings and QSqlDatabase won't open. I've found this website: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_load_a_sql_driver_correctly but it seems to be outdated and vague. Any known solution to the problem?

Comment: What kind of MinGW64 build do you using? I can suggest to switch into MSYS2 build, and follow the build instructions https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?117,425191,425191

Comment: @VictorGubin I am not using MinGW at all, I've installed only 64bit MSVS2017 and UWP compilers, and CDB debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MSVS you need `qsqlmysql4.dll`, usually need to build your MySQL drives from sources, you can follow [Qt documentation How to Build the QMYSQL Plugin on Windows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers) to do that.

Comment: I've build the plugin as instructed but I've got qsqlmysql.dll and qsqlmysqld.dll files, not a qsqlmysql4.dll file. Copying libmysql.dll and the other DLLs I have to different locations (like where the EXE is located or to plugins/sqldrivers) still gives me "QSqlDatabase: MYSQL driver not loaded" error. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add library to sql in Creator? its working for me.

Comment: yes, thank you, it's working now, I did sth stupid and didn't notice, never mind :D