# How to setup MySQL with MSVC and QMake?

Tags: mysql, qt, visual-c++

I am dealing with setting up MySQL in Qt and VC++ compiler.

The problem is that after running this command, MySQL is not found:

qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"

I am using Qt 5.13.1 (MSVC 2017 64-bit) console but if I use MinGW qt console, MySQL will be detected without any problem!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Microsoft Command Prompt and the Problem finally solved.

Answer (score 0):

Install the mysql connector
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

And read up in the developer guide
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/

Especially 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-notes.html

on my computer you find the dll in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\lib2

Comment: Thanks @nbk! I read Qt doc in here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers. Also I found this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573522/libmysql-dll-for-64bit-qt-w-msvs2017-compiler. But still I can't find out what I should do exactly! did you build MySQL with MSVC for Qt successfully?